# Horizontal Menu bar - UL/LI - Button hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a page, I have a horizontal menu bar using UL/LI.  It's within a bootstrap skin.

I have a code example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsgho7xe/

I attempted to use DIV's instead here: https://jsfiddle.net/afh6nox2/

As with the example(s) above, you'll see that for the "CNN" button, the text is not centered vertically.

Previously, I had used Table/Table-Cell display types to get this vertical alignment but had to change the code since the buttons weren't collapsing properly as the resolution dropped.

This way once 768px is achieved, the buttons collapse into a vertical list; this works great for both mobile and desktop.  But a side-effect is that the text is no longer vertically aligned.

Thank you for your time and attention..

```
<ul class="MenuLinks">
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/culturalinstitute/beta/asset/architecture-tel-aviv-israel/jgHSJFEie5q9HQ" target="_blank">White City of Tel Aviv</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.msn.com/en-us/weather/topstories/hottest-arctic-year-on-record-triggers-massive-ice-melt/ar-AAlvEi4?OCID=ansmsnnews11" target="_blank">Arctic Report Card NOAA</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="_blank">CNN</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://foxnews.com" target="_blank">Fox News</a>
  </li>
</ul>

.MenuLinks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul.MenuLinks {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #294273;
  width: 60%;
  font-family: roboto;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

ul.MenuLinks li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 14px 30px;
}

ul.MenuLinks li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

ul.MenuLinks li:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #c88d0c;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  ul.MenuLinks li {
    float: none;
  }
  .MenuLinks {
    display: inherit;
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to make CNN aligned little bit down when menu is horizontal?

Comment: Yes.Personally, it doesn't bother me, but someone else wants everything centered when the menu is displayed horizontally; the default showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below CSS and all the menu Item will be aligned center in vertical mode:

```
ul.MenuLinks li{
    margin:auto 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Didn't think that doing that would have centered it like that.  It does center it vertically.

Comment: Didn't think that doing that would have centered it like that.  It does center it vertically.  But of course, I head the "why are there spaces above and below the CNN button now".

Comment: we imposed margin to be taken care auto. That makes it center align vertically. Isn't that you want?

Comment: Yes, that portion works correctly.  But it was pointed out to me that when you hover over CNN (as compared to the other buttons), the highlighted hover doesn't cover the full height.  There is still a blue "bar" above and below the hightlighted button.  I'm not sure how to fix this since the buttons are different heights, and locking in a height will mess with the dynamic portion of this.